# What is the correct syntax for attaching a php handler to MySQL this?

Tags: php, mysql

Hey there I have this snippet and I am having trouble deducing the correct syntax for it. It is helping me search my DB and I cannot seem to get it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Here is the snippet its a PHP portion searching m y MySQL DB

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT e.event_name, v.venue_name FROM tie_in.events e LEFT JOIN tie_in.venues v ON v.venue_id = e.venue_id WHERE e.event_name = '%.$uniqueId.%' OR v.venue_name = '%.$uniqueId.%' ORDER BY e.event_time");
```

There area that I am having trouble with is the wrapping of the `$uniqueId` handler. How would I wrap this properly with parentheses etc to have the proper syntax to complete the function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pattern matches with `%` wildcards need to use `LIKE`, not `=`.

You can interpolate PHP variables inside strings by enclosing them in curly braces.

```
... WHERE e.event_name LIKE '%{$uniqueId}%' OR v.venue_name LIKE '%{$uniqueId}%' ...
```

Be careful that `$uniqueId` is a safe variable to use in SQL. You don't want to introduce SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Also, for what it's worth, [the mysql_* functions are deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli), and will be removed from PHP in some future version. So I recommend you use PDO instead, unless you have to use mysql_* because you have a lot of legacy code.

Answer (score 0):

Either remove the `%` since wildcards are not supported when you use `=`

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT e.event_name, v.venue_name FROM tie_in.events e LEFT JOIN tie_in.venues v ON v.venue_id = e.venue_id WHERE e.event_name = '$uniqueId' OR v.venue_name = '$uniqueId' ORDER BY e.event_time");
```

Or use `LIKE` instead of `=`

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT e.event_name, v.venue_name FROM tie_in.events e LEFT JOIN tie_in.venues v ON v.venue_id = e.venue_id WHERE e.event_name LIKE '%".$uniqueId."%' OR v.venue_name = '%".$uniqueId."%' ORDER BY e.event_time");
```